# Are block sizes fixed in hardware or can be reprogrammed in C or asm?

Tags: c, caching, assembly, buffer, block

I focus on C and assembly and I'm reading about the various uses of various block sizes e.g. for caching, buffering and likewise. Is block size used in the same way in buffering as in cacheing and the block size is just a `# define`in the C-code how much to buffer like when we do buffered i/o? Or is block size somehow fized in hardware and can't be manipulated be the programmer? What are other uses of blocks than caching and buffering?

Comment: Are you referring to block sizes for a file system? Or for other block devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block size is set by the operating system essentially and can be specified when creating the file system.  For instance, I have block sizes of 4096Kb in my NTFS partition, and my page file is located on this partition.  Therefore, the pages will correspond to these blocks of size 4096kb.